# Trying to increase item in a python list to get all options

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a list of numbers and increase them by a certain amount(1 in my example) up to a certain range(5 in my example) but for some reason it's not doing it the way I was expecting:

Given this list:

```
[1, 5, 7, 9, 3]
```

I expect:

```
[1, 5, 7, 9, 3]
[2, 5, 7, 9, 3]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 3]
[4, 5, 7, 9, 3]
[5, 5, 7, 9, 3]
[1, 6, 7, 9, 3]
[2, 7, 7, 9, 3]
[3, 8, 7, 9, 3]
[4, 9, 7, 9, 3]
[5, 10, 7, 9, 3]
```

... and so on

Here's my code:

```
# create list
list_of_nums = [1, 5, 7, 9, 3]
# variable of increase
increase_range = 5
range_per_increase = 1

for idx, i in enumerate(list_of_nums):
  current_item = i
  while current_item < i+increase_range:
    copy_of_list = list_of_nums
    current_item = current_item+range_per_increase
    copy_of_list[idx] = current_item
    print(copy_of_list)
    break
```

Output:

```
[4, 7, 9, 11, 5]
[4, 8, 9, 11, 5]
[4, 8, 10, 11, 5]
[4, 8, 10, 12, 5]
[4, 8, 10, 12, 6]
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a easier way to get the output I want?

Update: I think my above example I get incrementals for each item then move on, but is it possible to get all combinations so the first item and the others item are incremented. I want all combinations for the lists within each numeric range while preserving the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way to get this. The built in [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) method can do most of the work.

```py
from itertools import product

list_of_nums = [1, 5, 7, 9, 3]
increase_range = 5
range_per_increase = 1

choices_list = []
for num in list_of_nums:
    choices_list.append([])
    currentAdder = num
    while currentAdder < num + increase_range:
        choices_list[-1].append(currentAdder)
        currentAdder += range_per_increase

print(choices_list) 
# Prints [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], ...] with all the options for each item.

print("\n\n\n")

for nums in product(*choices_list): # Unpack choices_list into product
    print(list(nums)) # Since each output should be a list, convert from tuple to list
```

Comment: WOW thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. Can I ask you a side question?

Is there a way to know in advanced the number of options? For example if add the product for loop and add it to a list then len the list then it shows 3125.

Comment: @Lostsoul You can calculate this mathematically.  In this example, you have 5 numbers in `list_of_nums`, each with 5 options, so there are 5 ^ 5 options. An exact formula is `ceil(increase_range/range_per_increase) ** len(list_of_nums)`. Just remember to import the `ceil` function before using this formula.